# How Growable is a WebSphere Work Manager

Tags: websphere

Quoting https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/asyncbns/tasks/tasb_workmanager.html:

> The maximum number of threads can be exceeded temporarily when the
>   Growable check box is selected. These additional threads are discarded
>   when the work on the thread completes.

I cannot find any documentation on just how far the maximum number of threads can be exceeded. Is it a fixed number over the maximum setting? A percentage? Limited by some other global configuration? Limited until JVM resources are exhausted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any upper limit when the WorkManager's thread pool is marked growable.  Knowledge center [documentation of the WSVR0630I message](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.messages.doc/com.ibm.ws.runtime.runtime.html) hints at this in stating that "the pool will continue to grow as long as work requests outpace the current number of available threads".

For reference, the full message is copied here:

> **WSVR0630I:** Growable thread pool "{0}" has been expanded beyond its initially-defined maximum capacity. The pool size is currently "{1}".
>
> **Explanation**   The specified thread pool has reached its predefined maximum size and will be expanded.
>
> **Action**    No immediate action is required; however, the pool will continue to grow as long as work requests outpace the current number
>   of available threads.

It looks like [PM13147](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM13147) added logging of the above message.